# I want to use a text string as my JQuery selector, how do I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr("id");
    var tabState = $(this).is(".selected");
    var showThis = ".selector-" + tab; 

    if (tabState == true) {
        $(NeedToConvertshowThisIntoObject).fadeIn(100);
    }
    else {
        alert(Something);
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use directly the var showThis ?

Comment: sorry, but seriously: [rtfm](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to convert anything. The below line will work perfectly if the selector is matched.

```
$(showThis).fadeIn(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(showThis)` should do it:

```
$(showThis).fadeIn(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(showthis) instead    $(NeedToConvertshowThisIntoObject)
for example:
$(showThis).fadeIn(100);

Best Regards
Li Satisfy